# ATI Randeon X1500, what to do?

Tags: 12.04, ati

I have a pc with ubuntu 12.04 installed, it has an ATI X1500 Randeon, it's a setup video of only 1024 x 768, what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your card is listed here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver under 'All these Radeon(HD) cards and derivatives have good 3D acceleration support'

`RV505/RV515/RV516/RV550     Radeon X1300/X1400/X1500/X2300`

Due to buggy hardware or drivers, your monitor's correct resolutions may not always be detected. For example, the EDID data block queried from your monitor may be incorrect. But, though a bit technical you can add them yourself.

> Adding undetected resolutions
>
> If the mode already exists, but just isn't associated for the particular output, you can add it like this:

```
xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600
```

> If the mode doesn't yet exist, you'll need to create it first by specifying a modeline:

```
xrandr --newmode <Mode``Line>
```

> You may create a modeline using the gtf or cvt utility. For example, if you want to add a mode with resolution 800x600 at 60 Hz, you can enter the following command: (The output is shown following.)

```
cvt 800 600 60
   # 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
  Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
```

Then copy the information after the word "Modeline" into the xrandr command:

```
xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
```

> After the mode is entered, it needs to be added to the output using the `--addmode` command as explained above.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions

See the source for methods to make the changes permanent.